# How to manage Security on web pages of .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, html, .net, web

I have a web system which is control from the url of pages like:

http://localhost/web/dlg/main.aspx?knd=in&Int=252&pID=-1&pLnk=-1&Lkp=false&parent=&systemInterface=true&ID=5

But there is a security problem because some of users has few permissions of pages and others dont have permissions, Also users can change the parameters of URL and access forbidden pages, so how can i control this, something like a token in URL?

Someone has a start for me about what can i search for?

Comment: Don't pass the values on the querystring, pass them as hidden field values, in the session etc.
There will be no querystring for them to manipulate then.

Comment: @TerryDelahunt but the users can change the values of hidden fields no?

Comment: No. Not in all likelihood.

Comment: Do you not have any server side validation checking to see if the logged in user is allowed to access that particular page?

Comment: @TerryDelahunt users can very easily change the values of hidden fields using most browsers, it only really hides the parameters from plain sight.

Comment: @DarkHippo Only for user logged, but if the user can get the request of a admin user which access a particular page, then i dont have how to control, because i create the modules/pages only in first login of user (here i check the permissions).

Comment: Ok, I *think* I follow, try reading about ASP.Net Identity, see if anything there can help. Sorry I can't be of more assistance

Comment: @Dark Hippo - 99% of people wouldn't even be aware that a) hidden fields are used and b) how to manipulate them in the browser.